# Gravity sort of like google gravity - javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html

So i've got a website where there's a canvas and a text input, in the text input I write whatever I want and it then shows up inside the canvas. What I'd like to do is for the text to fall down and sort of bounce around almost like [google gravity](http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google-gravity/). Here's what I've been looking at so far [Gravity Bottom](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_gravity_bottom).

This is the important parts of my code so far:

```
<script>
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : createElementOnDom('CANVAS','myCANVAS'),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 500;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.gravity = 0.05;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;

        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,document.body.childNodes[0]);

        }

}

    function createElementOnDom (type,id) {
   var element=document.createElement(type);
   element.id=id;
   return element;
}
function myFunction() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCANVAS");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("Box").value,10,50);
}
</script>
<style>
canvas { 
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body onload="startGame()">
<br>
    <input type="text" name="Box" id="Box" value="" placeholder="Write whatever"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```